# Key Bindings for complex gui

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I am trying to get my application to respond to keyboard input. Eventually, I would like it to register ctrl+f and initiate a search, but I started simple and tried for the space bar. The Java tutorials on using Key Bindings got me this far, but no matter what I apply the key binding to, nothing registers. In the below code, panel is a JPanel and the others are assorted swing objects which have been added to panel.

```
    Action ctrlF = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           System.out.println("Action performed");
        }
    };
    panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"),"crtlF");
    openStallsList.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"),"crtlF");
    openStalls.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"),"crtlF");
    stallScroller.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"),"crtlF");
    assignLabel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"),"crtlF");
    tenantInfo.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"),"crtlF");
    unitSpinner.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"),"crtlF");
    buildingAddress.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"),"crtlF");
    buildingLogo.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"),"crtlF");
```

What am I missing here? Does it have something to do with focus? There are a couple of assorted labels and buttons which are not included on that list. Is there any way to get panel to register all of the input from all of it's children?

Thanks

Comment: Try using `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0))` instead

Comment: The try using something like `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK))`

Comment: Where is the action specified? (eg panel.getActionMap().put("crtlF", ctrlF ) )

Comment: Where would I try these things? It doesn't seem to be a valid object for the put method...

Comment: Instead of `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE")`

Comment: The action is specified in the constructor of a JMenuItem which triggers this to display.

Comment: panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0),"crtlF"); --

Still does not work...

Comment: You could also use `JComponent#getInputMap(int)` and pass it `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` on the core component, this will allow you to establish a global action, but this will depend on what it is you are trying to achieve

Comment: Did you bind `"crtlF"` to the `ctrlF ` `Action` via the `ActionMap`?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not... the find function needs to be specific to the building menu item which triggered the panel...

Comment: All I have done is what I posted... is there a special way I need to do that?

Comment: Probably panel.getActionMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0),"crtlF"); or some such, doing my research...

Comment: Yep, without adding an Action to the ActionMap that corresponds to your InputMap key, your code does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need bind a `KeyStroke` to some kind of "key".  Now personally, it's eaiser to specifiy the virtual key then using a `String`, as the `String` value can be a little temperamental, but that's me

```
panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0),"crtlF");
```

Next, you need to bind the "key" to an `Action`

```
panel.getActionMap().put("crtlF", ctrlF);
```

See [How to use key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details.

The next problem you will have is the component will need to be focused before the key binding can be triggered

You could try and get the `InputMap` with a different focus requirement using either [`WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT) or [`WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW) which will allow you to change the focus level required by the component in order for the key binding to be triggered.

i.e.,

```
int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap(condition);
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0),"crtlF");
//... etc
```